# Back side of child element with 3d transform dont hide if parent have backface-visibility: hidden

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

So I have parent element with styles

```
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

And I want to set 3d transforms to child element

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

But when I do so, back side of child don't hide with its parent. Of course, I can set

```
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

to child also, but is there other way?

http://jsfiddle.net/9eCTM/3/ (hover to rotate)

Comment: Is opacity an option ? ( http://jsfiddle.net/9eCTM/5/ )

Comment: no, Im looking for some property to set on parent, to hide back sides of children with its own. Or a way to do that. I thought `transform-style: preserve-3d;` would help, but it didn't..

Comment: I would say this shouldn't be the defined behaviour, but I am not sure. The only other way I can think of would be -webkit-backface-visibility: inherit;